# str.format() -> how to left-justify

Tags: python

```
>>> print 'there are {0:10} students and {1:10} teachers'.format(scnt, tcnt)
there are        100 students and         20 teachers
```

What would be the code so that the output became:

```
there are 100        students and 20         teachers
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
print 'there are {0:<10} students and {1:<10} teachers'.format(scnt, tcnt)
```

While the old `%` operator uses `-` for alignment, the new `format` method uses `<` and `>`

Comment: For completeness, using `<` and `>` for left and right justify, instead of just a `-` flag, allows for additional justification format codes, like `^` for center justify.  See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)